# Problem with JavaScript and adding a div to a grid at a specific (row, column) position

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

I want to add a new grid member to the html code using an external JavaScript file, but it is not working and I don't know why.

I want to make a large `grid`, like an oversized chess board, where I can position a `div` at any row or column.

```js
function Tile(tilex, tiley) {
  this.tilex = tilex;
  this.tiley = tiley;

  this.initTile = function initTile() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = ("tile" + tilex + "_" + tiley);
    div.className = "tile";
    div.innerHTML = "X";
    div.style.gridColumnStart(tilex);
    div.style.gridColumnEnd(tilex + 1);
    div.style.gridRow(tiley);
    div.style.gridRowEnd(tiley + 1);
    getElementById("tileGrid").appendChild(div);
  }
}

tile7_1 = new Tile(7, 1);
tile7_1.initTile();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(236, 150, 119, 0.726);
}


/*15 25*/

.grid {
  display: grid;
}

#tileGrid {
  background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  padding: 2px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(15, 20px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(25, 20px);
  grid-auto-columns: 20px;
}

.tile {
  background-color: rgba(100, 200, 100, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgb(20, 20, 20);
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid" id="tileGrid">
  <div class="tile" id="tile1">1</div>
  <div class="tile" id="tile2">2</div>
  <div class="tile" id="tile3">3</div>
  <div class="tile" id="tile4">4</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very interesting problem.

The problem, as you so rightly indicate, is in the JavaScript file.

The first problem I can see is the way you are setting `div.style.gridColumnStart` in the `initTile` function (also known as method). `grid.style.gridColumnStart` is not a function, but a setting (also known as property), so you should just assign a value to it with `=`. This is the same for the three other function calls which you have tried to make: `div.style.gridColumnEnd`, `div.style.gridRow`, and `div.style.gridRowEnd`.

The second problem I can see is the way that you are using the variables inside of your inner function `tilex` and `tiley`. These variables are not visible at this point due to global, local, function, and block scoping of variables. So, you should refer to them as `this.tilex` and `this.tiley`.

So the four function calls you tried to make should be:

```
div.style.gridColumnStart = this.tilex;
div.style.gridColumnEnd = this.tilex + 1;
div.style.gridRow = this.tiley;
div.style.gridRowEnd = this.tiley + 1;
```

Also, you should call `getElementById()` on the `document` object.

```js
function Tile(tilex, tiley) {
  this.tilex = tilex;
  this.tiley = tiley;

  this.initTile = function initTile() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = ("tile" + this.tilex + "_" + this.tiley);
    div.className = "tile";
    div.innerHTML = this.tilex + "_" + this.tiley;
    div.style.gridColumnStart = this.tilex;
    div.style.gridColumnEnd = this.tilex + 1;
    div.style.gridRow = this.tiley;
    div.style.gridRowEnd = this.tiley + 1;
    document.getElementById("tileGrid").appendChild(div);
  }
}

let tile7_1 = new Tile(7, 1);
tile7_1.initTile();
let tile2_6 = new Tile(2, 6);
tile2_6.initTile();
let tile4_3 = new Tile(4, 3);
tile4_3.initTile();
let tile7_7 = new Tile(7, 7);
tile7_7.initTile();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(236, 150, 119, 0.726);
}


/*15 25*/

.grid {
  display: grid;
}

#tileGrid {
  background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  padding: 2px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(15, 20px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(25, 20px);
  grid-auto-columns: 20px;
}

.tile {
  background-color: rgba(100, 200, 100, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgb(20, 20, 20);
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid" id="tileGrid">
  <div class="tile" id="tile1">1</div>
  <div class="tile" id="tile2">2</div>
  <div class="tile" id="tile3">3</div>
  <div class="tile" id="tile4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a side note, how do I make the id the same as the object name? I want to change this part " div.id = ("tile" + this.tilex + "_" + this.tiley); " so that it gives an id based on the name of the object. So if I made an object of the tile class, and I called it "blueTile", the id automatically becomes "blueTile".